# Apache and Mysql on XAMPP 3.2.1 not Starting

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have two xampp installed, both have two different PHP versions. when I run xampp with old PHP everything is running smoothly. but when I run xampp with the latest PHP, Apache and MySQL can not be run, always bring up the word "attempting to start mysql service" and "attempting to start the apache service". I've tried to change the ports for Apache and MySQL, but everything is useless.
oh, I get an error message like this:

```
11:07:51  [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
11:07:51  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
11:07:51  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:07:51  [Apache]  Found Path:"D:\file3\install\xampp1\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:07:51  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp1\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:07:51  [mysql]   MySQL Service detected with wrong path
11:07:51  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
11:07:51  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:07:51  [mysql]   Found Path: D:\file3\install\xampp1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=d:\file3\install\xampp1\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
11:07:51  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp1\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
11:07:51  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
11:07:51  [main]    Control Panel Ready
```

but if I change the PATH then xampp with old versions of PHP will not be able to run, right? What should I do? No one can help me?

Comment: Backup first. You'd better uninstall both XAMPP , and re-install the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall both XAMPP's and reinstall the latest version.

---

1) Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features
2) Find the XAMPP installation and uninstall it
* Do this for both that you see

You will also want to check if XAMPP is still installed as a service.

1) Hit the windows button and type "services"
2) Look for it in the list that you see

If it won't uninstall here's a post that may help: [How to uninstall XAMPP when it won't uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978740/how-do-you-uninstall-an-xampp-installation-that-refuses-to-uninstall)